# For an inner product space $V_K$, for which fields $K$ is the discriminant is a complete invariant of the form?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, discriminant

The discriminant is an invariant of a general symmetric bilinear form on a vector space $V$ over a field $K$. I'm trying to understand for which fields the discriminant is a complete invariant.

First i'll consider the two dimensional case. Say that we have a diagonalized form have nonzero diagonal entries $a,b$. Then its discriminant is $ab$. A second diagonalized form with the same discriminant has entries $1$ and $ab$. We need that there is a change of basis between these two diagonalizations.

Say that the basis of the first form is $u_1,u_2$. Then $(u_1,u_1)=a$, $(u_2,u_2)=b$ and $(u_1,u_2)=0$. If $v_1$ is the first basis element of the second basis, we have that $(v_1,v_1)=1$. Say $v=xu_1+yu_2$. Then $1=(v_1,v_1)=ax^2+by^2$.

Assuming such a solution exists, how would we define the second basis element $v_2$ of the second basis so that $(v_2,v_2)=ab$?

After I figure out how to define $v_2$, I believe that the discriminant will be a complete invariant of the form as long as $\forall a,b \in K$ the equation $1=ax^2+by^2$ has a solution.

Is there a way I could generalize this to dimensions higher than $2$?

Thanks! Also, I wouldn't mind general insights into what's going on here in addition to my specific questions. Thanks again!

Is this reasoning all clear? How would I generalize this to dimensions higher than $2$? Thanks

Comment: Witt, in his paper which introduced Witt rings, showed that over any field of characteristic $\neq 2$, in dimension 2 and 3 quadratic forms are uniquely identified by their discriminant and Hasse invariant (which is $(a,b)$ for your notation). For higher dimensions, he showed the same thing if over the base field every form in $\ge 5$ variables is isotropic, which includes $p$-adic and many function fields. For general fields he left the question open, but I'm sure there's more knowledge today. https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~v1ranick/papers/wittform.pdf

Comment: Oh perfect!! I love German!!